# Use SharePoint 2013 "Working on it..." during ajax call

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, ajax

I'm trying to use the SharePoint 2013 "Working on it..." during ajax call.
This is the code:

```
function ShowWaitDialog() {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);
}

function BuildTable() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ShowWaitDialog, "sp.js");

    //Do something

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.close();
};
```

The animation loads but never closes becouse on `SP.UI.ModalDialog.close()` I get the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'close'".

But on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410259(v=office.14).aspx I see that the `close` method exists.

Some suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Please check the answer posted here, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/88925/47153

Comment: Hello, I already found that thread and didn't worked for me. I get the same error "Object doesn't support property or method 'close'".

Comment: I answered a similar question here. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156504/modal-dialog-window-ui-wont-load-before-code-behind/156659#156659

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You call your method `showWaitScreenWithNoClose` using asyncronously with callback `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`. If `sp.js` is not loaded, then closing event can fire before the wait dialog is showed.

Your code should look like this:

```
var waitDialog = null;

function BuildTable() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
        waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);

        // DO SOMETHING;
        DoSomeWorkUsingAjax(myCallBack)


    }, sp.js);
}

function myCallBack() {
    if (!fIsNullOrUndefined(waitDialog)) {
        waitDialog.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
        //or SP.UI.ModalDialog.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, in my situation in the DO SOMETHING part I've to call something like `$.when(ajax1(), ajax2()).done(function() { CallAfterAjax(); });`. In this situation where I've to call `myCallBack` method? Thank you

Comment: Try this `$.when(....).done(myCallBack);

Comment: Hello, I tried as you suggested but it didn't works. I debugged it with IE Developer Tools and Firebug putting a breakpoint inside `myCallBack` and it never has been called. Does it means that my Ajax call don't end?

Comment: I put `function () { alert('Hello World'); }` inside `.done()` and it shows.

Comment: Then try `function () { myCallBack(); alert('Hello World'); }`

Comment: Sorry, before when the debugger didn't passed for `myCallBack` was a my mistake. Now It's solved. Anyway on `waitDialog.Close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);` I've always the same error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'close'"

Comment: Wait a moment, I replaced `Close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);` with `close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)` and now it seems works! :O But I tried it a lot of time before and Always gave me that error... Thank you anyway

Comment: Sorry for my typo error that have misleaded you. I corrected the answer. I'm glad your code is working now.

Answer (score 10):

You need to call `close()` on object returned from `showWaitScreenWithNoClose()`. This works for me:

```
var loading = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);
loading.close();
```

Comment: Hello I already tried it, I get the same error "Object doesn't support property or method 'close'".